# openssl genrsa. How to create a key standard pkcs # 15

Tags: openssl, standards, rsa

How to create RSA keys, private and public. Using md5 and mandatory standards PKCS#15?

I'm doing this:
Сreate private key with md5.

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048 -md5
```

Create public key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout > public.key
```

p.s and even how to find out from the key established standard?

Comment: I can't understand your question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: in short - is there a command to determine the standard key? and how to make binary type of keys.